# basic linear algebra question, proving it is a diagonal matrix and scalar matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A = $(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ such that $AB = BA$ for every square matrix $B$ of order $n$.

$(I)$ Prove that $A$ is a diagonal matrix. 
[Hint: Let $B_i$ denote the matrix whose $(i,i)$ entry is $1$, and $0$ elsewhere. Show
that $a_{ij} = 0$ whenever $i ≠ j$.]

$(II)$ Prove that $A$ is a scalar matrix. 
[Hint: For $i ≠ j$, let $B_{ij}$ denote the matrix whose $(i,j)$-entry is $1$ and $0$ elsewhere.Show that, $a_{ii} = a_{jj}$ for all $i ≠ j$.]

Can someone help me with this question using basic linear algebra concepts? Thanks.

Comment: The hints are pretty much a complete solution. My suggestion: Take $n=2$ and work out the hints in full detail.

Comment: you can look at the bigger picture with similar matrices, I have just asked about the same thing:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425317/if-a-invertible-so-ab-sim-ba/1425347#1425347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) You have the matrix $(B_i)_{kl}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{il}$, where $\delta_{rs}$ is the matrix with only $1$'s in the diagonal and the rest zeros.

The multiplication $AB_i$ is then
$$(AB_i)_{rs}\,=\,\sum_{r}A_{rk}(B_i)_{ks}\,=\,\sum_{k}A_{rk}\,\delta_{ik}\delta_{is}\,=\,A_{ri}\delta_{is}$$
Thus $AB_i$ is the matrix with all zeros except for its $s=i$-th column which contains the $i$-th column of $A$ -given by $A_{ri}$ where $r=1,\cdots,n$.

Analogously the multiplication $B_iA$ gives
$$(B_iA)_{rs}\,=\,\sum_{k}(B_i)_{rk}A_{ks}\,=\,\sum_{k}\,\delta_{ir}\delta_{ik}\,A_{ks}\,=\,A_{is}\delta_{ir}$$
This, however, is is the matrix with all zeros except for its $r=i$-th *row* which contains the $i$-th *row* of $A$ -given by $A_{is}$ where $s=1,\cdots,n$.

From the arrangement of both results, you can readily infer the conclusion sought. Indeed, a "*row* matrix" (by that I mean it's all zeros except within a given row) can never be equal to a "*column* matrix" (analogous but within a column) unless all values of the row in one matrix and the column in the other are zero, except maybe the diagonal elements in each case. This means 
$$A_{ri}=0 \; (r\neq i)$$

ii) Let's consider now the matrix $B$ whose entries $k,l$ are $(B_{ij})_{kl}=\delta_{ki}\delta_{jl}$. Proceeding as before we see that $(AB_{ij})_{rs}=A_{ri}\delta_{js}$ and $(B_{ij}A)_{rs}=\delta_{ri}A_{js}$. Equating this two results, and considering that the deltas bound the values of $r$ and $s$ to $i$ and $j$, respectively, leads to $A_{ii}=A_{jj}$.

We can call that number $a$. Thus we have proven that $A=a\mathbb{1}$ a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: @shabchels Did you solve it? Was this helpful? If so, it would be nice if you check on accepting this solution. Thanks.