# If $A$ invertible so $AB\sim BA$

Tags: linear-algebra

> 1.Prove If $A\in \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$ invertible so for every $B\in \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$ ,  $AB\sim BA$,
>
> 2.find a counterexample if $A$ is not invertible

1. If $A$ is invertible so there is a matrix $P$ a group of elementary row operation matrices such that $PA=I$ lets look at $P\cdot A\cdot B\cdot P^{-1}=(PA)(BP^{-1})=I(BP^{-1})=BA$ (as $P^{-1}=A$)
2. Is $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\0& 0\end{pmatrix}$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 &0\\1&0
   \end{pmatrix}  ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof for 1 is correct. That is, we can simply take $P=A^{-1}$.

For 2, the example you have chosen is not a counterexample. One idea is to choose $A,B$ so that $AB=0$ but $BA\neq 0$.

How about The same $A$ with
$$
B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}?
$$