# Square Matrix, diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A = (a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ such that $AB = BA$ for every square matrix $B$ of order $n$.

(i) Prove that $A$ is a diagonal matrix.

(ii) Prove that $A$ is a scalar matrix.

How to solve it? I actually started by letting $B$ also be $B_i$ where the $(i, i)$ entry is $1$ and $0$ elsewhere. How do I continue?

Comment: may i know wheres the duplicate question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425259/basic-linear-algebra-question-proving-it-is-a-diagonal-matrix-and-scalar-matrix

Answer (score 1):

HINT: take $B_{ij}$ which has $(i,j)$ - entry is $1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: i dont know how to continue... i started from that actually

Comment: @JosephLopez, do the 2 by 2 case. Put symbols in $$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right). $$ There are four tasks for you to do, then. The first is $B =B_{11}.$ Write out $AB$ and $BA$ carefully in the symbols, compare them. This will give one or more relationships among $a,b,c,d.$ The other three $B_{ij}$ matrices will lead to other relationships.